# Nodejs custom npm package "bin" command not found

Tags: npm, command, package.json, bin

I created a simple app for youtube channels management locally, it work fine when i run it on my environment, but when I want to check it globally it not working.

I tried first locally linking, then checking it like this `sudo npm link`, It link everything correctly but then when tried to use my command of my package it didn't work.

I also publish it to npm, but still not worked. I removed the package-lock.json & node_modules by typing:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

and then reinstall it, but still not working.

Help me please.
I just want to use `run` command for starting my application/pkg

This is my Package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "ytlocal",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/hamzaxeros/ytlocal.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "youtube",
    "channel",
    "youtube-locally",
    "youtube-channel",
    "youtube-manager",
    "youtube-management",
    "youtube-channel-local"
  ],
  "author": "Hamza Hussain",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/hamzaxeros/ytlocal/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/hamzaxeros/ytlocal#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "inquirer": "^8.2.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0"
  },
  "bin": {
    "run": "src/index.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: ooh i FOUND OUT, How to solve this particular point, Basically we will to make the entry point executable by typing `chmod +x ./src/index.js` thats it, then it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ooh I FIND OUT, how to get rid off this point, basically we will need to make the entry point executable by tying :

```
chmod +x ./src/index.js
npm link
run
```